# VB conversion to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-conversion, asp.net-roles

I've used a converter to change vb to c# and one of the lines originally is:

```
Dim roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles()
Dim roleNames() As String = roles.Where(Function(x) x.ToLower() <> "Admin").ToArray()
```

When the conversion returns I get:

```
dynamic roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
string[] roleNames = roles.Where(x => x.ToLower() != "Admin").ToArray();
```

Which then throws the error:

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or
>   expression tree type.

I've tried a few different ways and a few different converters, but I dont get any different results.

Why does it work fine in vb and not in c# if the conversion is correct?

Comment: Late binding with C# (using `dynamic`) can't pick up on extension methods. Try changing `dynamic` to `var` and see what happens.

Comment: @willaien It actually fails on trying to use a lambda before it even gets to trying to resolve the extension method.

Comment: That's a simple fix. You know in vb what Dim does I would assume so how is it declared in C# ... I would worry about learning the syntax instead of converting code...

Comment: @Servy: Fair enough. It would then blow up on the extension method as well. This is why code converts should be treated gingerly and reviewed.

Comment: just a quick observation but would x.ToLower() ever = "Admin"? Shouldn't that be x.ToLower() != "admin" as the .ToLower() would convert all casing as such?

Comment: @CharlesMay Yet another reason to use a case insensitive comparer rather than trying to hack it with `ToLower`.

Comment: Dim wasn't the issue @Codexer, but thanks for the useful advice...

Comment: roles.Where(x => x.ToLower() != "Admin") Is where it keep blowing up.

Answer (score 7):

> Why does it work fine in vb and not in c# if the conversion is correct?

Because the conversion isn't correct.  You shouldn't be using `dynamic` here.

```
var roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles(); 
string[] roleNames = roles.Where(x => x.ToLower() != "Admin").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `dynamic` with `var`.

As Servy points out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934509/vb-conversion-to-c-sharp#comment57601777_34934554) this happens because the VB code is compiled with `strict off` and the only way that C# can avoid type checking is with `dynamic`. As there's no compile time checking, should you get your converted code to compile with `dynamic` there's a good chance you'll hit run time errors.

If you turn `strict on` before the conversion process you should get better results, but you'll probably have to fix all the errors that that generates first.

For more information on the `dynamic` keyword see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

Comment: It makes the mistake because the VB code is compiled with strict off, and in virtually all cases, the only way to replicate that in C# is with `dynamic`.  Worse still, the conversions will only rarely fail to compile (namely when lambdas and extension methods are involved).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to explicitly create `roles` as a string array:

```
string[] roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
string[] roleNames = roles.Where(x => x.ToLower() != "Admin").ToArray();
```